# When operator delete() in assembly deletes vptr pointer?

Tags: c++, vtable, vptr

The vptr is deleted when operator delete() is called.

But the vptr pointer is hidden, and we don't have to care about its memory structure (plus each compiler has a different system on how it works.)

I'd like to know when exactly the vptr in an object that I just made is deleted in assembly.

Here is the assemble code(void operator delete(void * pUserData) ) from VS2010

```
10315980  mov         edi,edi  
10315982  push        ebp  
10315983  mov         ebp,esp  
10315985  push        0FFFFFFFEh  
10315987  push        10350F48h  
1031598C  push        offset _except_handler4 (10319550h)  
10315991  mov         eax,dword ptr fs:[00000000h]  
10315997  push        eax  
10315998  add         esp,0FFFFFFF4h  
1031599B  push        ebx  
1031599C  push        esi  
1031599D  push        edi  
1031599E  mov         eax,dword ptr [___security_cookie (103604BCh)]  
103159A3  xor         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax  
103159A6  xor         eax,ebp  
103159A8  push        eax  
103159A9  lea         eax,[ebp-10h]  
103159AC  mov         dword ptr fs:[00000000h],eax  
    _CrtMemBlockHeader * pHead;

    RTCCALLBACK(_RTC_Free_hook, (pUserData, 0));

    if (pUserData == NULL)
103159B2  cmp         dword ptr [ebp+8],0  
103159B6  jne         operator delete+3Dh (103159BDh)  
        return;
103159B8  jmp         $LN10 (10315A55h)  

    _mlock(_HEAP_LOCK);  /* block other threads */
103159BD  push        4  
103159BF  call        _lock (102496F0h)  
103159C4  add         esp,4  
    __TRY
103159C7  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  

        /* get a pointer to memory block header */
        pHead = pHdr(pUserData);
103159CE  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
103159D1  sub         eax,20h  
103159D4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax  

         /* verify block type */
        _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));
103159D7  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]  
103159DA  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+14h]  
103159DD  and         edx,0FFFFh  
103159E3  cmp         edx,4  
103159E6  je          operator delete+0A9h (10315A29h)  
103159E8  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]  
103159EB  cmp         dword ptr [eax+14h],1  
103159EF  je          operator delete+0A9h (10315A29h)  
103159F1  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]  
103159F4  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+14h]  
103159F7  and         edx,0FFFFh  
103159FD  cmp         edx,2  
10315A00  je          operator delete+0A9h (10315A29h)  
10315A02  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]  
10315A05  cmp         dword ptr [eax+14h],3  
10315A09  je          operator delete+0A9h (10315A29h)  
10315A0B  push        offset string L"_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID"... (1021CD48h)  
10315A10  push        0  
10315A12  push        34h  
10315A14  push        offset string L"f:\\dd\\vctools\\crt_bl"... (1021CCE0h)  
10315A19  push        2  
10315A1B  call        _CrtDbgReportW (103145F0h)  
10315A20  add         esp,14h  
    10315A23  cmp         eax,1  
10315A26  jne         operator delete+0A9h (10315A29h)  
10315A28  int         3  

        _free_dbg( pUserData, pHead->nBlockUse );
10315A29  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]  
10315A2C  mov         eax,dword ptr [edx+14h]  
10315A2F  push        eax  
10315A30  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
10315A33  push        ecx  
10315A34  call        _free_dbg (10316920h)  
10315A39  add         esp,8  

    __FINALLY
10315A3C  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0FFFFFFFEh  
10315A43  call        $LN7 (10315A4Ah)  
10315A48  jmp         $LN10 (10315A55h)  
        _munlock(_HEAP_LOCK);  /* release other threads */
10315A4A  push        4  
10315A4C  call        _unlock (10249740h)  
10315A51  add         esp,4  
$LN8:
10315A54  ret  
    __END_TRY_FINALLY

    return;
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I reread your question several times, and I'm still not quite sure I understand what you're asking...

Comment: Is this a case of Overthinking It? Can you please post the relevant C++ code?

Comment: @littleadv I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I just wanted to know where, in that assembly code, the vptr(pointer to VTable) becomes unusable(NULL)

Comment: @KerrekSB The only reason that I tagged "C++" is because vtable and vptr is definitely from C++. But anyway thanks about reading and being interested in this.

Comment: @YayCplusplus and what makes you think it ever does?

Comment: @littleadv Well I was just very curious about how the vptr pointing to the VTable is deleted and that assembly code must delete the vptr at some point, although I am not quite sure about which part of the code.

Comment: @YayCplusplus: The vptr is, almost certainly, just like another class member, only not accessible directly. So it's destroyed along with the object, just like any other member, with no need for any special deletion.

Comment: @YayCplusplus: Strictly speaking, vtables are a programming technique *used to implement C++* -- they're not part of the language :-) On the other hand, `operator delete()` **is** part of C++, so I was wondering how that tied in.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Oh, didn't know that. I think I just had my curiosity about this shattered. Thanks!!

Comment: @KerrekSB Ohhhh I see. I thought C++ started vtables. Thanks!

Comment: @YayCplusplus: People have known how to do objects in C way before C++. In a way, C++ was made to codify existing practice into the language, if you will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Caveat**: This is an implementation detail. Standard C++ does not dictate how virtual functions should be implemented, and doesn't know what a vtable/vptr is.

The vtable for a type has static duration (meaning it is around for the entire lifetime of the program).  Each instance of the type has a vptr to that shared vtable.  So the instance does not delete the vtable, because it does not own it.

The storage for the vptr (not the vtable it points to) is part of the instance, and gets deleted with the instance.

During construction/destruction the vptr is set to the vtable for each base class as they are being constructed.  Not seeing the most-derived type is the reason people warn against calling virtual functions in the constructor -- you might not be calling the function you expected to be calling.

The vptr is unusable once the final destructor has been called.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe here:

```
_free_dbg( pUserData, pHead->nBlockUse );
```

Vptr is part of object, and cannot be deleted separately.